# Emulators list is empty

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2017

With Visual Studio 2017, I've been building and testing an Android app for a while. Now, all of a sudden, the list of emulators is empty:

[image]

How do get the list back again?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed now.

It turns out that when VS was switched to "Release" mode, the list of emulators returned. But, switching back to "Debug" lost the list again.

In "Release" mode, I switched to a different emulator/simulator. After doing that and switching back to "Debug", everything was fine again in both modes!

[image]

Comment: Hey Glen, thanks for reporting! I am the dev lead for the Tools for Apache Cordova at Microsoft. Can you help me understand exactly how you got into this state? Do you have clear repro steps?

Comment: I really don't know how it started!  And haven't tried to replicate again.

Comment: You can email me at mbraude@microsoft.com and I'll route it.